# Product moved from Cat to Sub-Cat not showing up on site search

Tags: magento

In Admin I created new subcats for my CyberPower category. When I search for BH1500 on our site for the product I get the whoops page. If I go step by step through our site to get to the product it works just fine.  Why is the URL missing, or nor showing the link properly?

http://www.unipower.com/products/ups/cyberpower/bh-series.html, is what shows up.

However this

http://www.unipower.com/products/ups/cyberpower/bh-series/BH1500.html

should be the right link.

New to Magento, help me if you can!!

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is run a reindex and flush your cache! Basically, your catalog URL rewrites are incorrect or out of date.

`System > Index Management` - Best to select all elements, choose the Reindex Data action and click the Submit button.

`System > Cache Management` - Flush Magento Cache